# Is there a performance gain in specifying the table name in joins and using explicit cast?

Tags: performance, postgresql-performance

Is there any performance gain by the interpreter of the query is I specify the table on a join and make the cast explicit?

Instead of

```
...
join table_join on field1_from = field1_join and field2_join = '2'
...
```

using

```
...
join table_join on table_from.field1_from = table_join.field1_join and table_join.field2_join::text = '2'::text
...
```

It seems that this should make the job of the parser a little easier

Comment: What data type is `field2_join`?  If that is a number you shouldn't compare it to a string. But in general, to find out if two queries are in the same way, check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using `explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)` to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good practice to use aliases to qualify tables etc

```
Select a.c1, b.c2
From table1 as a
 ....
```

However, that has very little to do with performance. Identifying each table etc is only a fraction of what the optimizer does and I would be surprised if it even is noticeable.